# Why checkpoint coordinator takes long time to get completing

Tags: apache-flink

We are POC flink(1.8) to process data in real time, and using global checkpointing(S3) and local checkpointing(EBS), deploy cluster on EKS. Our application is consuming data from Kinesis.

For my test e.g I am using checkpointing interval 5min. and minimum pause 2min.

The issue what we saw is:
It seems like flink checkpointing process would be idle for 3-4 min, before job manager get complete notification.

here is some logging from job manager:

```
2019-07-10 11:59:03,893 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 4 @ 1562759941082 for job e7a97014f5799458f1c656135712813d.
2019-07-10 12:05:01,836 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 4 for job e7a97014f5799458f1c656135712813d (22387207650 bytes in 58645 ms).
```

As my understanding the logging above, the `completedCheckpoint`(CheckpointCoordinator) object has been completed in 58645 ms, but the whole checkpointing process took ~ 6min.

This logging is for 4. checkpointing, But the first 3 checkpointing were finished on time.

Comment: And it is regardless how big or small the check point interval am i using.

Comment: this issue has been resolved by flink 1.8.1